# TextBox no me selecciona el texto al hacer click en el

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicacion que tiene un formulario principal (frmPrincipal), dentro de el hay varios elementos, uno de ellos un groupbox, y a este groupbox se le han añadido como controles varios formularios(frmClaves, frmDatos,...).
Cada uno de estos formularios tiene varios elementos, entre ellos varios textbox.
Para que la aplicacion funcione correctamente se ha definido la propiedad TopLevel a false.

```
public frmClaves()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetTopLevel(false);
        }
```

Esto es necesario porque sino al agregar el formulario al groupbox falla.
El problema que tengo es que al hacer esto los TextBox contenidos en estos formularios no funcionan como normalmente lo hacen, es decir, si hago click y arrastro el raton deberia seleccionar todo el texto por el que pasa, pero no selecciona nada.

Lo curioso es que en un textbox normal cuando haces click y arrastrar el raton, el texto se selecciona y el cursor del raton deja de parpadear, pero en los formuarios que tienen el TopLevel a false, cuando haces click y mantienes clickeado, el cursor sigue parpadeando y al arrastrar el raton no hay ningun cambio.

Si alguien sabe como puedo solventar esto o darle a los textbox de estos formularios el comportamiento original se lo agradeceria mucho,

Un saludo.

Comment: Alguien me ha modificado la pregunta porque tiene varias faltas de ortografia, se lo agradezco, pero es que me he equivocado y le he dado mal, asi que esos cambios no se han reflejado.

Comment: Curiosamente, haciendo doble click en el textbox,si que selecciona todo el texto no?

Comment: efectivamente @Pikoh , haciendo doble click me selecciona el texto sobre el que se hace doble click, si pongo "erase una vez" y hago doble click sobre "erase" me selecciona "erase".

Comment: el problema principal es haber agregado formularios dentro de un groupbox, cuando lo que se deberian haber agregado son controles personalizados. Me parece que el tema viene por ahi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema parece ser algun bug de .Net. Para solucionarlo, puedes añadir lo siguiente:

```
public frmClaves()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.SetTopLevel(false);
}
```

O bien:

```
public frmClaves()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ControlBox = false;
    this.Text = "";
    this.SetTopLevel(false);
}
```

Eso hará que funcione, aunque perderás la barra de titulo del formulario. Aunque esa puedes simularla por código en tu formulario.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh!!!

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

la función `toplevel` sino me equivoco establece que sea o no seleccionabl el texto que contiene el formulario, supongo que lo estará des habilitando de dicho formulario

Podrias emplear el uso de MDI , Interfaces de documentos multiples

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms233676(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229722(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.ingenieriasystems.com/2013/11/Trabajando-con-Interfaces-de-Multiples-Documentos-MDI.html

Comment: eso me temo yo tambien, pero no se si hay alguna manera de que siga permitiendo seleccionar dicho texto sin que deje de ser toplevel.

Comment: si le colocas el top level en true, que problema ocurre?

Comment: hola Victor el sigueinte codigo -> gbContenedor.Controls.Add(creaInstanciaPantalla(pantalla.Nombre)); falla, salta ArgumentException, necesita que sea toplevel a false poorque "Top-level control cannot be adder to a control"

Comment: trata de agregar a tu pregunta un poco mas de codigo para ver en que puedo ayudarte

Comment: Gracias Victor, el tema es que necesito agregar formularios a un control, pero para poder hacer esto toplevel debe ser false, y al ser toplevel false se pierde el comportamiento estandar de los textbox

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Por favor mantener los comentarios como comentarios. Si necesitan una charla extendida por favor usen el chat.

Comment: estuve leyendo sobre c# y no es recomendable hacer el embevido de paneles en lo form, lei algo y sugieren usar MDI https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229722(v=vs.110).aspx